# HMAC SHA1 with NSData input Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, encryption, hmac

I need to hash a NSData input with HMAC-SHA1. I used this code:

```
- (NSString *)HMACSHA1:(NSData *)data {
    NSParameterAssert(data);

    const char *cKey = [@"SampleSecretKey012345678" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const void *cData = [data bytes];

    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

    NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];\

    /* Returns hexadecimal string of NSData. Empty string if data is empty. */

    const unsigned char *dataBuffer = (const unsigned char *)[HMAC bytes];

    if (!dataBuffer) {
        return [NSString string];
    }

    NSUInteger dataLength = [HMAC length];
    NSMutableString *hexString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:(dataLength * 2)];

    for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; ++i) {
        [hexString appendFormat:@"%02x", (unsigned int)dataBuffer[i]];
    }

    return [NSString stringWithString:hexString];
}
```

but the hex string output is always wrong (checked from server). I think the problem is this line:

`const void *cData = [data bytes];`

because if convert data (sample "test" string) in the same way as key:

`const void *cData = [@"test" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

then check the result using this page: [HMAC crypt](http://myeasywww.appspot.com/utility/free/online/Crypt_Decrypt-MD5-AES-HMAC-SHA-DES-RABBIT/en?command=UTILITY&ID=2), the result is matched.

If I hash a NSString then I can use `cStringUsingEncoding:` but I can't figure out convert NSData to `const void*`. Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common Crypto supports HMAC with SHA1, MD5, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512 and SHA224.

Here is an example implementation that is a little simpler, not sure if it resolves yourproblem since no input/desired output was supplied:

```
- (NSString *)HMACSHA1:(NSData *)data {
    NSParameterAssert(data);

    NSData *keyData = [@"SampleSecretKey012345678" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableData *hMacOut = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1,
           keyData.bytes, keyData.length,
           data.bytes,    data.length,
           hMacOut.mutableBytes);

    /* Returns hexadecimal string of NSData. Empty string if data is empty. */
    NSString *hexString = @"";
    if (data) {
        uint8_t *dataPointer = (uint8_t *)(hMacOut.bytes);
        for (int i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
            hexString = [hexString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%02x", dataPointer[i]];
        }
    }

    return hexString;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I never think about just use `data.bytes` and `data.lenght` instead of converting data to cString. How stupid.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise to use [CommonCrypto framework from Apple](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-36064/Source/Digest/sha1.c) as you have hardware accelerated SHA calculation.

I don't know if it's HMAC (as far as I can see it is supported, but didn't try), but I'd consider switching your server (or whatever) to be compatible, as on the iOS side it's much faster with hardware support.

**Edit**: You can read more about the topic at this [SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5387310/849616).

**Edit 2**: At Github there is also a [nice wrapper](https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZSwiftCommonCrypto) (Swift) for CommonCrypto. Anyway, it will give you an idea how to implement it and what does CommonCrypto support.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I think I still need to read more and more about cryptology to understand those things :)